# cannot clone git repository

Tags: git, terminal, openshift

Get this message when trying to clone Openshift git repository from terminal:

```
Cloning into 'staples'...
ssh: connect to host staples-pankajt.rhcloud.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pankaj:staples pankajtripathi$ rhc ssh staples
Your authorization token has expired. Please sign in now to continue on
openshift.redhat.com.
Password: **********
Connecting to 55c3cbe67628e199a90000db@staples-pankajt.rhcloud.com ...
ssh: connect to host staples-pankajt.rhcloud.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Can you ping staples-pankahit.rhcloud.com?  It looks like there might be a problem with that machine.

Comment: yes I am able to ping to staples-pankajt.rhcloud.com

Comment: Do you get any response to `ssh staples.pankahit.rhcloud.com`?

Comment: Pankaj:StaplesAPI pankajtripathi$ ssh staples.pankahit.rhcloud.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname staples.pankahit.rhcloud.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Whoops.  That was supposed to read `ssh staples-pankahit.rhcloud.com`.